# Proving solutions of a system of differential equations satisfy certain equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$\left\{\begin{matrix} x'=x+y-xy^2\\  y'=-x-y+x^2y
>  \end{matrix}\right. $$
>   and $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2\ln|xy-1|.$
>
> Prove that for every solution satisfying $x(t)y(t)\neq 1$ there exists a constant $C$ such that $u(x(t),y(t))=C$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$

I tried adding/subtracting the equations in order to achieve something like $$\frac{df(x,y)}{dt}=0$$

and it didn't really work. Also, I don't see any other way of solving it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Connection with Lyapunov functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* calculate the derivative of $u$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: @user365248 If $x(t),y(t)$ solve your initial system then $x'$ and $y'$ are...

Comment: This simplifies to zero, check your calculations.